# Calling multiple WCF and asmx web services dynamically without generating proxy or using WSDL

Tags: web-services, wcf, wsdl

We connect with multiple (20-30) third-party web services within our C# Batch Application. We are attempting to find the best way to call these web services dynamically (without generating proxy or using wsdl). All the third party agencies endpoints or URL's will be configured in database table. Client app will check the URL at run-time and make a service call. We are not worried about async calls it’s all synchronized process.

SQL Table : Client-configuration

```
Client         URL                                      Method   IsActive
A              http://serverhost/ClientA/Service1.svc   Submit   1
B              http://serverhost/ClientB/Service2.asmx  Submit   1
```

The only issue is we are not sure about the third party service implementation is WCF or asmx. I have read few articles online to use HttpWebRequest to call web services dynamically (without generating proxies/wsdl.)
Is this the best way to implement this or any concerns I need to think of?

Please see below ex:

```
public static void CallWebService(string xml)
    {
        var _Url = "http://serverhost/ClientA/Service1.svc";
        var _action = "http://serverhost/ClientA/Service1.svc/Submit";
        try
        {

            ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] data = encoder.GetBytes(xml);

            XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope(xml);

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_Url);
            webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", _action);
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            webRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";

            Stream webStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream();
            webStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            webStream.Close();

             WebResponse  response = webRequest.GetResponse();
             Stream  responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

             using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
             {
                 string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
             }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            responseStream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream();
        }

} 

Here is the details shared by one of the client.
http://setup.localhost.com/ClientA/Service1.asmx  
Operation : Submit

SOAP 1.1
The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be   
replaced with actual values.
POST /ClientA/Service1.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: setup.localhost.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://setup.localhost.com/Submit"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
 <Submit xmlns="http://setup.localhost.com/">
  <eCitXML>string</eCitXML>
  <eCitPdf>base64Binary</eCitPdf>
  <eCitKey>string</eCitKey>
 </Submit>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Body>
 <SubmitResponse xmlns="http://setup.localhost.com/">
  <SubmitResult>string</SubmitResult>
 </SubmitResponse>
 </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
 SOAP 1.2
 The following is a sample SOAP 1.2 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be    
 replaced with actual values.
 POST /ClientA/Service1.asmx HTTP/1.1
 Host: setup.localhost.com
 Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
 Content-Length: length

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap- 
 envelope">
<soap12:Body>
 <Submit xmlns="http://setup.localhost.com/">
  <eCitXML>string</eCitXML>
  <eCitPdf>base64Binary</eCitPdf>
  <eCitKey>string</eCitKey>
 </Submit>
 </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap- 
 envelope">
 <soap12:Body>
 <SubmitResponse xmlns="http://setup.localhost.com/">
  <SubmitResult>string</SubmitResult>
 </SubmitResponse>
</soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Comment: .svc = WCF, .asmx = Legacy web service.   Have you tried the code to see if it works?

Comment: I tried the code with different end points but it didn't work ,throws exception every time .

Answer (score 0):

I think your question could be rephrased as

*Is there a generic method to call any SOAP 1.1 or 1.2 web service operation without prior knowledge of the service operation except for the SOAP action and URL?*

I'm assuming that all the third party web services expose a common operation which accepts and returns the same types.

If this is the case then providing you model the service operation contract correctly you could use ChannelFactory to call all the services.

Calling WCF services is [straightforward](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681(v=vs.110).aspx) in this manner, but to call asmx services you'd need to do a [bit more work](http://blog.bodurov.com/blog/Create-a-WCF-client-for-asmx-web-service-without-using-web-proxy). So your client code would need to know if the service was asmx or wcf, and moreover, if wcf, whether the service is soap 1.1 or 1.2.

I must say I'm struggling to understand what advantage you will have once you have achieved this. I can see the value if you owned all the 20+ services you were calling, but this clearly is not the case.

Granted, you won't have a ton of nasty generated service reference code, but the whole point of WSDL is it allows for machine generated service contracts. If the third party services make any breaking changes you'll need to manually synchronize these inside your client code, rather than just regenerating the client.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'll update the question details. Here is the details shared by one of the client.

Comment: I have updated the question section with client details, its a asmx service shared by one of the client, please review.Thanks